# Muscle wire considerations

Tags: actuator

I am in the planning stages of a project for my new son/daughter, who will be arriving in December. The project involves using muscle wire to make bug or bird slowly flap it's wings. The form will be made of fabric or foam.

Has anyone ever worked with muscle wire, and have some advice or warnings or painful lessons you learned that you could pass on?

My plan is to use a micro to energize the muscle wire (through transistors if the current draw is too great). This will cause the muscle wire to retract, pulling on the fabric wing and make the wing look like it's flapping.

This may not be the correct forum for such a question, but I'll ask anyway and hope for a favourable response. There is a lot of collective experience and knowledge among the users here, so I'm hoping to access some of that.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the suggestions. Lots to think about.

I should have mentioned this was going to be a mobile. You know, the kind that spin around above the babies crib? So my thought was muscle wire for low weight and silent movement. However some very good considerations have been made.

Comment: You too, huh? My second son is due in December. A big, ceiling mounted display sounds fun. Fabric or foam makes this sound large-ish... I'd suggest servos. My experiments with muscle wire weren't good either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The experience I have had with muscle wire was never good.

- Massive power consumption
- Gets hot
- Slow
- Doesn't seem to last a long time, maybe stretches.
- You can't solder to it.

I once made a butterfly with flapping wings. For that I used simple ammeter coil type actuators. You can buy these from a company called [Plantraco Microflight](http://www.microflight.com/).

[image: Plantraco micro actuator.]

If I remember correctly, their resistance is so high that you can actually drive them directly from the pins of a microcontroller.

You can put together a nice butterfly from a couple of these, and a PIC. Don't forget to have some optical fibre antennae, illuminated by LEDs.

[image: Robot Butterfly]

And here's a terrible quality [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrShy20p2VQ) of it moving.

Comment: +N - very cute.

Answer (score 1):

I actually started a similar project based on this [Origami Flapping Crane](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1448) just to learn more about shape memory alloys. I built the circuit to switch the power on and off so it would flap by itself but shelved the project for more important things before actually playing with the nitinol itself. So I have no first hand experience to share, but I do have some research that I did that may help you.

First is a good article discussing the [pros and cons](http://robotics.hobbizine.com/flexinol.html) of using shape memory alloys. There are certainly pros to using shape memory alloys such as low weight, small size, and no magnetic noise among others. But there are also the aforementioned cons. This article gives it a fair assessment in my opinion and is worth a read of you plan on working with it for whatever reason.

That article links to [another article](http://robotics.hobbizine.com/ulndrive.html) by the same author that gives the design for a drive circuit utilizing a PIC 16F690 and ULN2003A. My application was much simpler so I just used a single transistor and a 555 but the microcontroller and the Darlington array would be very useful for more complex projects.

Finally is a paper on the [Technical Characteristics of Flexinol](http://www.dynalloy.com/pdfs/TCF1140.pdf). What I found really interesting about this paper was the description of different actuator configurations and the stroke versus force table for each. They show that by placing shape memory alloys in certain mechanical configurations, you can drastically increase the stroke and force of your actuator.

Answer (score 0):

Non muscle-wire suggestion follow on from rocket magnet:

Nitinol (muscle wire) has its place, but power efficiency is not good.
 Possible alternatives:

- RC servo.
  These can be had at low cost and in very small sizes.
  Speed can be as slow as you wish
  Easy to drive with a microcontroller.
  More power efficient than Nitinol
  No power consumed when static at any given point.
- Stepper motor.
  Low cost and smallish size.
  Can scavenge from defunct printers.
  Speed easily enough variable - step by step or even microstepping between steps is not too hard.
  Ask me about processor controlled microstepping if of interest.
  More power efficient than Nitinol
  No power consumed when static at any given point.
- Small DC motor - maybe a pager motor. 
  Using bare motor only is more for switching from one end to other end of travel.
  Versions with gearboxes available at lowish cost - allow slow speeds.
  More power efficient than Nitinol
  No power consumed when static at any given point.
  Can use screw thread for DIY gearbox.
- Loud speaker cone
  DIY equivalent of rocketmagnets butterfly system.
- Hard disk actuator.
  Much on web re driving.
  Speed controllable.
  Power usually higher than some alternatives but needs not be.
  No power consumed when static at any given point.
- Automotive 2 coil meter movements (used for eg fuel gauge)
  True servo drive
  Very low power drive 
  Far more power efficient than Nitinol
  No power consumed when static at any given point.
- Novel - fan with speed controlled motor
  Wing position set by air flow.
- ... ? :-) There will be more.

Some of these are less quiet than others - you judge.